# Should phonon energy be undefined at zero frequency?

Tags: solid-state-physics, phonons

The energy carried by phonons of frequency $\omega$ is given by

$$
E = \hbar \omega n_b(\beta \hbar \omega) = \hbar \omega \frac{1}{exp(\beta \hbar \omega) - 1}
$$

So when $\omega = 0 $, the energy is $0 * \frac{1}{0} = 0 *$  Undefined, or undefined. I would expect the energy to go to zero at zero frequency (no oscillations, no energy), so I'm wondering why it doesn't. Appreciate any help.

Comment: The limit is well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\lim_{\omega \rightarrow 0} \frac{\hbar \omega }{e^{\beta \hbar \omega}-1}=
\lim_{\omega \rightarrow 0} \frac{\hbar \omega }{\beta \hbar \omega +\frac{(\beta \hbar \omega)^2}{2} +\dots} =\frac{1}{\beta} \lim_{\omega \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\beta \hbar \omega }{2}+\dots}=\frac{1}{\beta} 
$$

Comment: Bonus Point: What about the Free Energy associated with that Phonon? Here we have $kb T Log{Z}$ where $Z = \frac{exp(\hbar \beta \omega)}{1 - exp(\hbar \beta \omega)}$. It doesn't seem like you can use the same trick to prevent the Log Z term from blowing up.

Comment: The partition function of one harmonic oscillator is $Z=\frac{exp(-\beta \hbar \omega/2)}{1-exp(-\beta \hbar \omega/)}$. This expression diverges for $\omega \rightarrow 0$, but this is understandable. In that limit there is no harmonic oscillator, but a free particle on an infinite straight line.